# Get value from the key before selected key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

Given the following object:

```
let test = {x: "a", y: "b"}
```

is it possible to get the value `"a"` with only the information `"y"` ?

For instance I know I can get the value `"b"` via `test["y"]` but is it possible to get the value "a" by only using "y" somehow?

something like the pseudo-code `test["y" - 1]`

I tried test.getIndex("y") so I can subtract 1 from that but that doesn't seem possible. Curious if this is doable!

Comment: If you want to get the _letter_ before `y` (in Unicode order), use `String.fromCodePoint("y".codePointAt() - 1)` as the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but *really really weird*. Strongly consider a different data structure if you ever find yourself needing something like this.

Take the object's keys, find the index of the key you're interested in in that array, then navigate to the previous key in the array to get its associated value.

```js
let test = {x: "a", y: "b"};

const keys = Object.keys(test);
const index = keys.indexOf('y');
console.log(test[keys[index - 1]]);
```

Generally, you should not depend on object property order - not because it's not guaranteed (it is), but because it leads to unintuitive code.